# I am running flutter app and getting this error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...                             362ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                      1,375ms
Xcode build done.                                            6.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Comment: To fix this I've just upgraded Flutter flutter upgrade and run pod install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Delete the flutter folder at the `FLUTTER PATH`, and recopy the same path in the flutter folder.